# Invoke-WMIMethod - Throws Error Not Found - SCCM CCM Actions

Tags: powershell, wmi, sccm

```
Invoke-WMIMethod -ComputerName $computer -Namespace root\ccm -Class SMS_CLIENT -Name TriggerSchedule "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000026}"  | Out-Null
Invoke-WMIMethod -ComputerName $computer -Namespace root\ccm -Class SMS_CLIENT -Name TriggerSchedule "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000027}"  | Out-Null
Invoke-WMIMethod -ComputerName $computer -Namespace root\ccm -Class SMS_CLIENT -Name TriggerSchedule "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000113}"  | Out-Null
Invoke-WMIMethod -ComputerName $computer -Namespace root\ccm -Class SMS_CLIENT -Name TriggerSchedule "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000108}"  | Out-Null)
```

All throw Not Found Errors.

Any ideas? Are these superseded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000026}` and `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000027}` are user specfic and seem to have been changed to a different class that is sid dependent so that you can invoke it for any user. The most common example to call them is

```
$sched=([wmi]"root\ccm\Policy\$sid\ActualConfig:CCM_Scheduler_ScheduledMessage.ScheduledMessageID='{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000026}'")
$sched.Triggers=@('SimpleInterval;Minutes=1;MaxRandomDelayMinutes=0')
$sched.Put()
```

Where $sid is the users SID with each `-` replaced with a `_`
You can get them for logged on users like this:

```
$sids = (get-wmiobject -query "SELECT UserSID FROM CCM_UserLogonEvents WHERE LogoffTime = NULL" -namespace "ROOT\ccm").UserSID.replace('-','_')
```

However `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000113}` and `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000108}` should still work with the method you used. The only reason to throw the Not Found error for those is if they are not executed with elevated admin rights, but that is the same for all the other TriggerSchedule messages as well so I don't know what the problem could be.

Comment: Please use straight quotes in code instead of the so-called 'smart-quotes' `“` and `”`

Comment: Sorry. Fixed it

Comment: yeah odd that 113 and 108 still fail. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: Those are both related to software updates, is there anything special configured in your environment regarding updates maybe?